Problem with RegionIntersection and Polygons with more than 4 points
I have a polygon with 6 points and an InfinteLine and want to find the intersecting line between both using RegionIntersection. Assume this:
poly = {{0, 
    0}, {20.3, -35}, {24.6, -32.5}, {27, -36.7}, {36.4, -31.3}, {13.7,
     7.9}};
line = InfiniteLine[{12.011, 6.925}, {0.5, -0.866}];
int = RegionIntersection[Polygon[poly], line]

This doesn't evaluate, but returns just this:

However, If I just remove any two 2 Points of the Polygon, it just works:
poly2 = poly[[{1, 4, 5, 6}]];
int = RegionIntersection[Polygon[poly2], line]
Graphics[{Gray, Polygon@poly2, Red, line, Blue, int}, Frame -> True]

returns:

What am I doing wrong here, or is this a bug?
V13.2.1 on Windows 11

Before Version 14.1,  we have to use Region[DiscretizeRegion@int]

You're not doing anything wrong. You code did evaluate, and the result you get is a valid region, with which you can do whatever calculation you want.
RegionQ[int]
(* True *)

RegionDimension[int]
(* 1 *)

ArcLength[int]
(* 45.2949 *)

RegionDistance[int, {0, 0}]
(* 13.8643 *)

The only noticable difference is that prior to version 14.1, BooleanRegion was not automatically visualized, so you have to do it by yourself:
PlotRegion[int]


